# Imagick Postscript delegate failed

Tags: ghostscript, imagick

I installed Imagick and gostscript on centOS7.
When I run convert --verbose file.pdf to file.png I get the bellow error:

```
convert -verbose file.pdf file.png
convert: Postscript delegate failed `[ghostscript library 9.25] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-21602hQquXpZq43Oi%d' '-f/tmp/magick-21602GaTn0ntZZtU8' '-f/tmp/magick-21602PKCCwOZwN1ZY'': Error: /undefined in 07ad60b6ae0c2980940853353748b78adfa20f1a3c71fcb728276b01b158e04cS▒
Operand stack:

Execution stack:
   %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   false   1   %stopped_push   2047   1   3   %oparray_pop   2046   1   3   %oparray_pop   2026   1   3   %oparray_pop   1884   1   3   %oparray_pop   --nostringval--   %errorexec_pop   .runexec2   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--
Dictionary stack:
   --dict:956/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:0/20(G)--   --dict:77/200(L)--
Current allocation mode is local
Current file position is 68
GPL Ghostscript 9.25: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
 @ error/ghostscript-private.h/InvokeGhostscriptDelegate/171.
convert: no images defined `file.png' @ error/convert.c/ConvertImageCommand/3235.
[ghostscript library 9.25] -sstdout=%stderr -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 '-sDEVICE=pngalpha' -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 '-r72x72'  '-sOutputFile=/tmp/magick-21602hQquXpZq43Oi%d' '-f/tmp/magick-21602GaTn0ntZZtU8' '-f/tmp/magick-21602PKCCwOZwN1ZY'[clixwmc@hostname AAA_Water_District_okamal_payclix_com]$
```

I tried all google solution I could find but with no success.
Anyone knows what is going on please?
Thanks.

Comment: You are using an elderly version of Ghostscript (9.25) That is 4 years old; try something newer. If it continues to fail then you should open a bug report and attach the input file. You will also need to know the **Ghostscript** command line, which appears to be part of the error message there.